# Python Program wont ever return "True"

Tags: python

So, I am working on this programming project, and these are the instructions for the project:

A list is sorted in ascending order if it is empty or each item except the last one is
less than or equal to its successor. Define a predicate isSorted that expects a list
as an argument and returns True if the list is sorted, or returns False otherwise. (Hint: For a list of length 2 or greater, loop through the list and compare pairs of items, from left to right, and return False if the first item in a pair is greater.)

This is what I made:

```
def isSorted(lst):  
  for x in range(len(lst) - 1):     
     if(lst[x] > lst[x + 1]):     
            return False    
            return True
# Testing
print(isSorted([]))
print(isSorted([1,2,3,4,5]))
print(isSorted([1,2,3,6,5]))
```

And these are the results I get:
[My Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFfc8.png)

I cant figure our why I don't get "True" as a result for the third line in the "Testing" part of the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I tried unindenting the `return true`

portion of the program, but now i get back the following error:

```
File <string>, line 5
    return True
     ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: The second `return` will never run, because there is another return in line above!

Comment: Looks like an indentation problem. remove an indentation before the return True.

Comment: Indentation in python matters, and `return True` is indented too far

Comment: You want `return True` to be after the for loop (not within the if statement which is within the for loop)

Comment: @Peterrabbit I tried moving the  ```return true``` over the the left, but I get back this error now:  ```File <string>, line 5
    return True
     ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function```

Comment: Then you moved it too far to the left.

Comment: It looks like you're indenting by pressing the spacebar an arbitrary number of times. Python does not like that – use the tab key, and a text editor that knows about indenting.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, the second if statement being indented on the same level is "dead code"

You can rewrite your loop and return statements using `all()`

```
def isSorted(lst):  
  return all(lst[x] < lst[x + 1] for x in range(len(lst) - 1))
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but now I get back the error: ``` File <string>, line 4
    return False    
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ``` Thios is what my program looks like now: ``` def isSorted(lst):  
  return all(lst[x] < lst[x + 1] 
   for x in range(len(lst) - 1)    
            return False    
            return True
        
# Testing
print(isSorted([]))
print(isSorted([1,2,3,4,5]))
print(isSorted([1,2,3,6,5])) ```

Comment: I don't get errors - https://ideone.com/7S9r84

Comment: well when I try it the way you show it works. it was my own dum dum mistake. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Looks like you kept the two return statements.

Answer (score 0):

Should be better like this

```py
def isSorted(lst):  
  for x in range(len(lst) - 1):     
    if(lst[x] > lst[x + 1]):     
      return False    
  return True
```